# screen turned upside down itself in ubuntu budgie 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, lts, xrandr, budgie

The screen of my laptop suddenly flipped on its own. At first it flipped **180 degree** and now it turns **90 degree**. After researching about it a lot I found the solution but **it is not permanent**.
My screen turns to normal after writing a command in terminal but it still flips whenever it wants.....

the command I use is simple:

> ```
>                               xrandr -o normal
> ```

So I am looking for want a permanent solution and also the reason behind it. If anyone can help me I'll be very thankful.

I'm using `Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.2 LTS 64-bit`.

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop has an accelerometer and if you tilt your laptop your screen orientation will follow.

This is standard - it is mainly for screens that can change its orientation.

You can disable this for your laptop by adding the rotation-lock applet from budgie-desktop-settings to your panel and activating it.

[image]

You don't need to permanently run the applet - you can remove it afterward if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir... but i want you to know that my laptop stays on table all the time and nobody moves it, the screen flip itself even when i'm looking some video... and i constantly need to use terminal and turn screen to its normal self...

Comment: Do try the applet to lock your screen orientation.

Comment: did that too but still same problem

Comment: Then it sounds like a bug because the screen orientation should be respected.  Please file a launchpad bug report so Canonical devs are aware - in a terminal type `ubuntu-bug mutter`

Comment: Thank you sir for suggestion, I send developers bug report with detail. Thank you again